# Elasticsearch windows service not work on Nano server

Tags: elasticsearch, nano-server

I am now trying to install ES on windows 2016 Nano server, it works when start ES in command line, but failed to start ES as windows service, maybe due to some changes on Nano server, but I have no hint at all why it didn't work.

Anyone has experience on installing ES on Nano server?

or Where can I get the source code of ES windows service, **elasticsearch-windows-x64.exe**? It could be helpful to troubleshoot the root cause.

Comment: What logs are saying?

Comment: Actually, when I run "service.bat install", the output is "installed successfully", BUT the service was not actually installed. Then I manually registered the service using sc.exe. But after I start the service, it just said "the service could not be started due to internal error". I did not find way to get event log on Nano server yet.

Comment: well first of all which version you try to install? and second look to ES folder there is logs folder where ES holds logs

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a chance to test it on Nano Server 2016, but I've installed ES 5.1.2 + JDK1.8.0_121 on Windows 2016 Server Core successfully and was able to start the service.

1. Install JDK and set SYSTEM ENV with `setx -m JAVA_HOME
   "C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"` command. It doesn't work with user level ENV variable such as using `set JAVA_HOME=xxx`.
2. unzip ES to `c:\elk\elasticsearch`
3. Edit the elasticsearch.yml config file, config the Cluster and Node names and save it
4. install the ES service `C:\elk\elasticsearch\bin>elasticsearch-service.bat install`
5. start the ES service `C:\elk\elasticsearch\bin>elasticsearch-service.bat start`

Reference:

- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18373
- http://blog.technotesdesk.com/setting-a-system-environment-variable-from-command-line-in-windows-server-2012-r2/

Comment: By "Server Core 2016", do you mean Windows Server 2016 Server Core, or Windows Server 2016 Nano Server?

Comment: It's "Windows Server 2016 Server Core", i haven't tried on Windows Server 2016 Server Nano yet